# Disable SublimeLinter for a large C file in a C++ project

Tags: sublimetext2, cppcheck

I have a C++ project with one very large C file (the excellent lightweight [mongoose](https://github.com/valenok/mongoose) web server) which *really* canes cppcheck.  Is there a way to disable the automatic lint for this file alone?

Or failing that, how can I switch off automatic linting for all C files, but keeping it on for C++?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit this file

```
/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter.sublime-settings
```

and add languages that SublimeLinter will ignore:

```
// An array of linter names to disable. Names should be lowercase.
"sublimelinter_disable":
[
],
```

You might also map this command to a key/combination:

```
{
    "caption": "SublimeLinter: Disable Linting",
    "command": "sublimelinter_disable",
    "args": {"action": "off"}
},
```